# How to bind object property to textbox in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-ngmodel

I am new to Angular and i am trying to bind the form which consists of text boxes from model object.
but i am receiving an  error like "Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:Can't bind to 'NgModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'"

i had invest lot of time in google but still problem exists

Below are my code.

**html:**

```
    <div>
     <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Project Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtProjName" [(NgModel)]="projectFieldsdtl.PROJECT_NAME" >
    </div>

     <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Project Manager Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtProjManager" >
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Project Manager Email ID:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtProjManagerMailID" >
    </div>
    </div>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
    import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
    import { FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';  
    import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
    import {SpotCheckStatusComponent} from './spotcheckstatus.component';

    @NgModule({
      imports:      [ BrowserModule ,FormsModule,HttpModule ],
      declarations: [ AppComponent,SpotCheckStatusComponent ],
      bootstrap:    [ SpotCheckStatusComponent ]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

**projectFields.ts**

```
        export class projectFields {
                public PROJECT_CODE:string;
                public PROJECT_NAME:string
                public PROJECT_MANAGER: string;
                public PROJECT_MANAGER_EMAIL_ID: string;    
        }
```

**SpotCheckStatusComponent.ts**

```
            import {Component,OnInit ,OnChanges} from '@angular/core';
        import {IMyDpOptions} from 'mydatepicker';
        import {HttpService} from './http.service';
        import { serviceLine } from './models/serviceLine';  
        import { projectFields } from './models/projectFields';  


        @Component({
          selector: 'my-app',
          styleUrls:['/css/home.css'],
          templateUrl:'./SpotCheckStatus.html',
          providers:[HttpService]

        })
        export class SpotCheckStatusComponent  implements OnInit
        {
             name = 'SpotCheckStatus'; 

             public projectFieldsdtl: projectFields[];  

          constructor(
            private httpService: HttpService
          ) {}

          ngOnInit(){

                  this.httpService.getProjectCode(serviceline).subscribe(
                  response=> {      

                    this.projectFieldsdtl=response[0];
                    },
                  error=> {
                      console.log("ERROR: ",error);
                      console.log(error.json()); //gives the object object
                  },
                  () => {
                      console.log("Completed");
                  }

                  );
            }
        }
```

And finally projectFieldsdtl got the object as below:

```
    [{
    PROJECT_CODE:"9999"
    PROJECT_MANAGER:"shekat"
    PROJECT_MANAGER_EMAIL_ID:"teja.ravi@gmal.com"
    PROJECT_NAME:"ABFL"
    }]
```

Comment: it should be `[(NgModel)]` not `[(ngmodel)]`

Comment: i used [(NgModel)] but still same error i recieved

Comment: Oh no, it should be `[(ngModel)]` small `n`

Comment: ok. after replacement with [(ngModel)] i have received another like "Cannot read property 'PROJECT_NAME' of undefined" :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have missed double quotes in the ngmodel.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtProjName" [(ngModel)]="projectFieldsdtl.PROJECT_NAME" >
```

### EDIT

Also you are using Array object in the ng-model. So it should be like `projectFieldsdtl[0].PROJECT_NAME` instead of `projectFieldsdtl.PROJECT_NAME`.

Because of the service aync calling . try this *ngIf=" projectFieldsdtl != null" on your div tag

```
<div class="col-sm-6 form-group" *ngIf="projectFieldsdtl != null && projectFieldsdtl != undefined">
        <label class="control-label">Project Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtProjName" [(NgModel)]="projectFieldsdtl[0].PROJECT_NAME" >
    </div>
```

And you should initialize an empty object in nginit function , try this below code

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.projectFieldsdtl=[{
    PROJECT_CODE:""
    PROJECT_MANAGER:""
    PROJECT_MANAGER_EMAIL_ID:""
    PROJECT_NAME:""
    }];
}
```

Comment: if i used with projectFieldsdtl[0].PROJECT_NAME i am recieving an error like 'Cannot read property '0' of undefined'

Comment: @user3301440 Because of the Aync issue. try this `*ngIf=" projectFieldsdtl != null"` on your div tag

Comment: Thanks Ramesh  for the answer this is working. but problem is if i use above *ngIf condition initially i can't see the textbox right?

Comment: @user3301440 Yes, So you should initialize the object in ng-oninit with the sample empty object. I have update the answer

Answer (score 2):

`ngModel` is case sensitive so you should put `[(ngModel)]` not `[(ngmodel)]`.

your second problem is when you received `undefined` model, it is due to `projectFieldsdtl` is undefined or contain `null` value.

in your `JS contructor()` consider initializing `projectFieldsdtl` to object.

```
// make sure to declare it as well
projectFieldsdtl: any;

constructor()
{
  // initialize its value
  this.projectFieldsdtl = {};
}
```

hope that helps

Comment: projectFieldsdtl  is not empty or null value. and i see that there is an object contains in projectFieldsdtl

Comment: and one more thing was if i tried to bind with [(NgModel)]="projectFieldsdtl" in textbox i see that [object] was binded

Comment: `public projectFieldsdtl: projectFields[]` this is an array not a object that is why you recieve an error on start

Comment: `[(ngModel)]="projectFieldsdtl"` this works because `projectFieldsdtl` is not undefined and later resolved by `http service` response which contains an objject

Comment: If you are expecting `projectFieldstl` to be an object just simply change this declaration `public projectFieldsdtl: projectFields[]` to `public projectFieldsdtl: projectFields` as the first declaration makes it an array at start

Answer (score 0):

Since you are getting array from service you can do like follow and use [(ngModel)]

```
    In Component

    public projectFieldsdtl: projectFields = {};  

    Service Response 

    this.projectFieldsdtl=response[0]

    template 

        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtProjName" [(ngModel)]="projectFieldsdtl.PROJECT_NAME" >





Another Way to implement

   <div *ngFor='let item of projectFieldsdtl; let i=index'>
                   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtProjName_{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="item .PROJECT_NAME" >
                    </div>

   In component 

   public projectFieldsdtl: projectFields[] = [];  

   Service Response 

   this.projectFieldsdtl=response;
```